# Facebook app: OAuthException: An active access token must be used

Tags: facebook, sdk

i am having the next problem migrating my old facebook app to Oauth 2.0:

when i try to read the user profile (in php code) i get the error: "**OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**"

The application makes the login operation via javascript and then it redirects to a page where from php i get the user profile.

The javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {   
    FB.init({
        appId   : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId() ?>',
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
        oauth : true    // enable oauth
    });

    // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location="index.php";
    });

};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());


function login () {
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     //console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       //alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       var url="./code.php";
       window.location=url;
     });
   } else {
     alert("Debes de identificarte y aceptar las condiciones para obtener el descuento");
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});

};


</script>
```

The php part (in code.php):

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();   
if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
.....
```

I have read different posts and tried things like getting the access_token from the javascript login response or from the cookie and then make the call to api('me/?access_token=...), but it didn´t work.

Edit: Thanks a lot to everyone, it's working now!!

Thanks

Comment: I may be missing something (it is 4:30am here), but are you calling the login() function? If you are, what is the debug output of response.authResponse?

Answer (score 1):

@moguzalp @brandwaffle @yauros,To get signed_request on non canvas app. i used the follwing code and it works for me.
If you are using Oauth 2.0 than u will get cookie named fbsr_app_id.This cookie is nothing but a signed_request.

You can get this cookie and parse the signed_request to get user id and access_token as follows:

```
$cookieName = 'fbsr_' . $app_id;

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}
function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
$fbsr=parse_signed_request($_COOKIE[$cookieName],$application_secret);

$user_id=$fbsr['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

@MehulHingu suggested solution fits your case

However, you can do better with: in your php code,  get&parse `signed_request` and extract `access_token`(if user is alread authenticate your app and give relevant permission) with your facebook php api

You will get `signed_request` when your canvas called: `https://app.faceobook.com/yourapp`

Otherwise with javascript login, you can do registration and asking permission easily.

When your registered user comes this method would be more efficient.

Note: As brandwaffle stated, this suggestion is valid if your app is canvas app

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java script FB.Login function then you will get an access token and user id in response as

```
var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
```

U can pass accessToken and user id to your php code via Ajax and use it in api calls in php.

And remember if you are logging in using java script FB.login then

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

will not work in php.

So to check whether user is logged in and authanticated use following code

```
    try {
    $me_arr = array(
    'access_token'=>$access_token ,    
    );
        $user_profile = $fb->api('/me',$me_arr);
        if($user_profile){
    // user is authanticated

                        }
    else
    {
    // not 

    }

      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        error_log($e);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's necessary to pass the access token along? I've always had good success using $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

Comment: Yes if u r making user login via java script then u will need to pass an access_token in every php api calls else u will get error "OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user" for sure.

Comment: I agree you need an access token, but you can get it on the PHP side without having to pass it in the URL. That's what getAccessToken is for :)

Comment: Thanks, it works. And like brandwaflle says it is possible to use $facebook->getAccessToken directly.

Comment: @yauros Did you see the update to my answer? It looks like your JS is logging the user out before the redirect...

Comment: Yes, lol!!, i remove that lines from the code. It made a logout. Things of copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Your JS code is logging you out right before it reloads the page. That will mess stuff up on the PHP side bigtime! :)

As long as the user is logged in and has approved your app via the JavaScript SDK, you should just need to get the access token on the PHP side to make everything work. I modified your example as follows:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();   
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $me = $facebook->api('/me' . $token);
```

I know you mentioned trying this example before, so it's worth knowing that your access token can be invalid while you are still logged into Facebook. This would result in passing the if($user) check, but attempting the API call with an invalid access_token. To ensure this isn't happening, var_dump out the $token value--if it's your app_id and secret separated by a '|', then you don't have a valid access token.

I was able to login on the JS side in a test app, then load the code on the PHP side and have it display my username. You can see it in action here: http://brandwaffle.info/facebook/